# Getting stuck at Django error: No module named registration

Tags: django

I installed the registration module, added it to settings.py.  When I tried to run syncdb (% python sitename/manage.py syncdb --settings sitename.devsettings)

It gave me "Error: No module named registration"

The same setup works (using the same files for everything) fine on the server.  This happens on my local machine running OS X.

I checked the sys.path, the path where registration module resides is listed, and the actual module is in place as well.  Since there is not much else being outputted, I am not sure how to debug further.  What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There may be Python errors in your `registration` models. Try starting a shell and importing them, instantiating them, etc.

Comment: Thanks this worked! The rest of the py files besides the models file also has to have no errors and be imported right.

Answer (score 30):

Since this page ranks nicely in Google, it seems like a good place for a general answer that might help.  Sometimes the folder name in svn/git is different than the folder name in settings.py -- a trap for the unwary.

So, if `INSTALLED_APPS` references your stuff as mywhatever.someapp then it is likely you want settings.py to be in the "mywhatever" folder, with a subfolder "someapp" that contains an `__init__.py` file.

Comment: +1 - This will likely help other newbies like myself.  Thanks!

Comment: I *always* forget to do this when I create an "apps" folder and I pull my hair out (well, I have no hair, but you get the point) until I remember to put an __init__.py file in the apps folder.

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS` seems to list all of the pip packages used by the Django app. None of those have folders directly in the Django project where settings.py is?

Answer (score 15):

You mention sys.path so you might have tried this, however this was my problem and I'm sure some people reading this have it too.

open the command prompt and enter (with the trailing slash):

```
export PYTHONPATH=pathto/myproject/
```

then enter:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

This allows me to edit the settings.py file to list the INSTALLED_APPS like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'myapp',
    'registration',
 )
```

instead of:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'myproject.myapp',
    'myproject.registration',
)
```

Comment: '...myproject.settings'

Answer (score 12):

I was simply missing a comma after the 'registration' entry in the settings.py file.  Once I added the comma after 'registration', 
Syncdb worked for me.

Comment: Im embarrassed to say this was my problem too

Answer (score 7):

just do this in your virtualenv

> pip install django-registration

Comment: also check to make sure you didn't install dif v of registration (i.e. django-registration-redux, et. all)

Answer (score 5):

Fixed! I had the same problem, I was trying to register submodules, like:

```
project
 organization
    categories
```

In my settings file I added

```
> INSTALLED_APPS = (
>     'django.contrib.admin',
>     'django.contrib.auth',
>     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>     'django.contrib.sessions',
>     'django.contrib.sites',
>     ...
>     'organization.categories',  )
```

When you generate a module in the folder categories you have a ***init**.pyc* I copied this file into "organization" folder, then I execute the following commands:

```
sudo python manage.py makemigrations
sudo ./manage.py syncdb
```

And it works file!

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem. I had saved the app in the project folder (as in, the same folder as manage.py), but referenced to "projectname.appname" instead of just "appname" in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

Answer (score 2):

I had this on SX with virtualenv too, after installing with PIP as per the docs.
I did another install using easy_install and after that, it all worked.

```
easy_install -Z django-registration
```

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this problem until a figured out that the enviroment was not activated.

Check if your Virtualenv is activated. If not, run in the shell

```
source .<enviroment name>/bin/activate
```

Comment: And also check if the environment you wanted is activated

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an entry in installed_apps, And you have the minimum 4 files in your apps. **init.py**, urls.py, models.py, and views.py

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be you haven't added `'registration'` into `installed apps` in the `settings.py` file.

Perhaps you are using a different `settings.py` (Or `localsettings.py`) on the server.

Comment: That wouldn't give that error. Anyway, he specifically states he has added it to settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

1) Put down the registration app inside your project as an app

and do the syncdb

---

do the below for finding out the exact cause of error

```
1.go to you project directory
2.python manage.py dbshell
3.in shell
4.import registration   
5.if you get error here which means your registration module is  not
there on the python path (or) some problem in finding that one.
if it works then some other problem like improper compilation .............
```

Answer (score 0):

If this happens to you on Windows and while using virtualenv, it's possibly because of virtualenv.

Install that package on the local (non virtualenv) environment and it should work.

I had the same problem with django-crispy-forms.

Answer (score 0):

When I've installed django-registration to my virtual env, I've had the same error. 
Don't know how it worked exactly, but when I've installed this lib to the main Python directory (not virtual env) the error has disappeared.

Maybe It will help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, was following old course, it creates a folder that has '-' in its name and puts all the modules in it.

the name was like "portfolio-project"
but I change it to "portfolio_project", solved the problem with importing

```
import portfolio_project.jobs.views
```

not

```
import jobs.views
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar error. and this was my installed apps setting in the settings.py.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'app_name',
]
```

However, this application folder was located inside the project folder, moving it to the same level as the project folder cleared the error.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem because I was messing up with my virtualenv.

I had two windows open:

1. Running the server
2. Running my commands

I had successfully installed the Django-registration package into my venv on my Windows computer:

```
$ . venv/Scripts/activate
$ pip install Django-registration-redux==2.0
```

But my server was not in the venv, so it could not find the package.

Stopped the server, entered venv in that window, then restarted the server and all is good.