# ImportError: No module named ShownameConfigcrispy_forms

Tags: python, django

I did pip install as asked:

```
pip install --upgrade django-crispy-forms
```

and there is my installed apps when running pip freeze:

```
django==1.10
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
freeze==1.0.10
PIL==1.1.7
PyAudio==0.2.9
six==1.10.0
```

But for some reason, when i'm trying to run the server, i get:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x00000000040CBF28>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py2.7.egg\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
    six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py2.7.egg\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py2.7.egg\django\__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py2.7.egg\django\apps\registry.py", line 85, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.10-py2.7.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 123, in create
    import_module(entry)
  File "C:\python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named ShownameConfigcrispy_forms
```

I searched in the internet to find out an answer. but no one got helped.
Somebody know why it's happening?

Edit:
`where pip`:

```
C:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe
```

`pip -V`

```
C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Web>pip -V
pip 8.1.2 from c:\python27\lib\site-packages (python 2.7)
```

`python -V`

```
C:\Users\micha\Desktop\Web>python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

Installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'showname.apps.ShownameConfig'
    'crispy_forms',
]
```

Comment: can you type `where pip` and post the results ?

Comment: Can you please post the output of `pip -V` and `python -V`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560968/importerror-no-module-named-crispy-forms might be helpful, good luck!

Comment: @Koga
make Edits.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre make edits

Comment: @Abd Azrad
been there. wasnt helpful. but thanks!

Comment: The problem is you have forgotten the comma after `'yourapp.apps.ShownameConfig'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.

Comment: It **is** the problem. The `INSTALLED_APPS` you posted is clearly missing the comma after `'showname.apps.ShownameConfig'`.

Comment: @Alasdair hoo... now im embarrassed :D.. THANKS.