# Error loading bootstrap3 from windows 8.1 in django

Tags: django, django-bootstrap3

I tried installing bootstrap using

```
pip install bootstrap3
```

then i got the error that the satisfied version was not found, so I tried

```
pip install django-bootstrap3
```

the bootstrap installed and is in the INSTALLED_APPS folder , but i still get an error trying to load it.
[Here is the error please any suggestions would be helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYMMW.jpg)

Comment: Hi Jasmin, development on Windows can be tricky. Are you using a `virtualenv` for your installed packages? On windows, I use `pip install virtualenvwrapper-win` to keep my project packages in their own distinct environments. As to the error itself, it appears that Django is expecting an app called `registation`. It may not be finding it in your `PYTHON_PATH`, which a `virtualenv` should address. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965755/getting-stuck-at-django-error-no-module-named-registration

Answer (score 0):

the error in not bootstrap3 related, django is trying to load an app named registration is failing. posible you named an app incorectly.